# git で、削除・追加・変更されたファイル一覧を取得するには？

Tags: git

git 上で、あるコミット A から別のコミット B までの間で、削除・追加・変更されたファイルについて、それぞれの一覧が取得したいです。

これを実現する方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: `git diff A..B --stat`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git diff --name-status A..B` で一覧が表示されます。

```
A    file1
M    file2
D    file3
```

行頭の A, M, D は、それぞれ追加, 変更, 削除されたことを意味します。